# in fit_generator, training_generator was influenced by validation_generator

Tags: keras

I met a strange problem in fit_generator

```
model.fit_generator(generate_arrays_from_file(trainSizeListImgDic[s], s, batchSize), steps_per_epoch=math.floor(size / batchSize), epochs=20,
                            verbose=2, validation_data=generate_arrays_from_file(testSizeListImgDic[s], s, batchSize),
                            validation_steps=vs,callbacks=[EarlyStoppingByAccVal(monitor='val_acc', value=0.90, verbose=1),checkpointer])
```

and my generate_arrays_from_file reads:

```
def generate_arrays_from_file( SizeListImg ,img_size,batch):
size = len(SizeListImg.images)
dim = re.split('[,()]', img_size)
dataX = np.zeros((batch, int(dim[1]), int(dim[2]), 1), dtype=np.float32)
dataY = np.zeros((batch, num_classes), dtype=np.float32)
loopcount  =  math.floor( size/batch )-1
if loopcount==0:
    loopcount = 1
counter = 0
while (True):
    i = random.randint(0,loopcount)
    for ind in range( (i*batch) , (i + 1)*batch ):
        try:
            dataX[counter, :, :, 0] = SizeListImg.images[ind]
        except :  
            print('dim='+ str(dim) )
            print('error counter=' + str(counter) + "  i="+str(i) + "  ind=" + str(ind) + "  batch="+str(batch) + "\n" )
            print("SizeListImg.images="+str( len(SizeListImg.images) ) )
            print( "img0 = "+SizeListImg.images_names[0])
            print("img1 = " + SizeListImg.images_names[1])
            print("img2 = " + SizeListImg.images_names[2])
            print("img3 = " + SizeListImg.images_names[3])

        for j, imgClass in enumerate(imgClasses):
            dataY[counter, j] = (SizeListImg.labels[ind] == imgClass)
        counter += 1
        if counter>=batch:
            yield (dataX,dataY)
            counter = 0
            dataX = np.zeros((batch, int(dim[1]), int(dim[2]), 1), dtype=np.float32)    #not tf.zeros((25, 200, 200, 1))  please noted different:  np.zeros(
            dataY = np.zeros((batch, num_classes), dtype=np.float32)
```

During training I found size of training images 139 be reduced to the size of validation images 22, and that lead to the index wrong but the images indeed came from training images set. However if I reduce batch from 20 to 10, no any error.
 Any conspiracy of fit_generator against me?

Comment: Of course reduce the batch no error. Since  training images shrink from 139 to 22, batch=10 can deal with this 22 images, but where were 117 images gone? I need them all.

Comment: Don't use comments to add to your question. That is what [edit] is for.